# How can I get the url of a file which is outside the jar?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin

I have deployed spring-boot application in exploded mode using maven-assembly-plugin. Target folder contains following structure:

```
+springdemo-0.0.1-application.zip
  +config
    +myfolder
      -profile.png
  +springdemo-0.0.1.jar       //running this jar file
  +start.sh
-springdemo-0.0.1.jar
```

I want url of profile.png file in the controller class.

I have tried this, but it gives me url: http://ip:port/config/myfoler/profile.png.

```
getImageDownloadUri("config/myfolder/" + filename)
public static String getImageDownloadUri(String imagePath) {
    return ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path(imagePath).toUriString();
}
```

I have also tried this, which gives me url: null

```
MainController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

Comment: What is the second `springdemo-0.0.1.jar`?

Comment: The jar file inside the zip is taken by assembly(get all the jar from project.build.directory) and the other one is created by maven build.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get the path reliably from inside the `springdemo-0.0.1.jar`, because it depends on where the JVM is launched from.  That said, you can do something like the following:

```
File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getPath();
```

Replace `MyClass` with the real class name.

Another option would be to set an environment variable pointing to the deployment directory, and then use that in `MyClass`.

Comment: @rupal3112 Which part of “You can’t get the path reliably” was not clear to you? Try the second option.

Comment: @rupal3112 No you've not tried the second option. Come back when you've.

Comment: @rupal3112 Learn the basics of application deployment, let's not waste time here..